# Why type cast works while selector doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, highlight

I want to loop through view and its subviews to highlight them. Firstly, I use selector like this:

```
func highlightViewAndSubviews(view: UIView, highlighted: Bool) {
    if view.respondsToSelector(Selector("setHighlighted:")) {
        view.performSelector(Selector("setHighlighted:"), withObject: highlighted)
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        highlightViewAndSubviews(subview, highlighted: highlighted)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when highlighted is false or view is `UILabel`. Then I use type cast to achieve this. It works perfectly.

```
func highlightViewAndSubviews(view: UIView, highlighted: Bool) {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
        imageView.highlighted = highlighted
    }
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        label.highlighted = highlighted
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        highlightViewAndSubviews(subview, highlighted: highlighted)
    }
}
```

My question is why. And I prefer selector because it works for label,button,image view and so on. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line doesn't do what you think:

```
view.performSelector(Selector("setHighlighted:"), withObject: highlighted)
```

Use key-value coding instead:

```
view.setValue(highlighted, forKey:"highlighted")
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain what this line does?